# Electromagnetic waves: are the two chiral options possible?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

Suppose we have sinusoidal electromagnetic wave travelling in the $+z$ direction. It is said that the electric field and the magnetic field must be mutually perpendicular and perpendicular to the direction of propagation. However, this leads to two possible options:

Option A:
$$\begin{aligned} \vec{E}\left(x,t \right) = E_{\text{0}} \cos{\left( kx-\omega t \right)}\hat{j} \\ 
\vec{B}\left(x,t \right) = B_{\text{0}} \cos{\left( kx-\omega t \right)}\hat{k} \end{aligned}$$
[image]

Option B:
$$\begin{aligned} \vec{E}\left(x,t \right) = E_{\text{0}} \cos{\left( kx-\omega t \right)}\hat{j} \\ 
\vec{B}\left(x,t \right) = -B_{\text{0}} \cos{\left( kx-\omega t \right)}\hat{k} \end{aligned}$$

[image]

Are both cases possible?

Comment: [Left and right handed electromagnetic radiation from different subatomic particles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/500392/46708)

Comment: I see... However, in classical electromagnetic theory the only possibility would be the first one, wouldn't it?

Comment: Your answer is right for electrons. Protons and positrons have not yet been explored.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I see that it is not. Form Maxwell's second equation, $$\nabla \times \mathbf{E}=-\frac{\partial \mathbf{B}}{\partial t}$$

So the sign of $\mathbf{B}$ is given by the sign of $\mathbf{E}$. Thus, option B would not be possible.

Comment: Also Google "Poynting vector" for related information.